# Python to get count of emails in INBOX - outlook - Microsoft Graph API - using access token- OAUTH2

Tags: python-3.x

Python to get count of emails in INBOX - outlook - Microsoft Graph API - using access token- OAUTH2

im trying to get number of emails in inbox using python.

1. Ap registration done
2. Permissions and grants are done  for all mail.read components

when i tried to call this API :

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/mailFolders/inbox

it returns

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Project Files\PY-OUTLK-INBX\outibx.py", line 76, in <module>
    result.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\pythonProject7\venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/mailFolders?$top=250`
```

here is the code:

```
`


import requests
import json
import msal
import atexit
import os.path
import sys
import os
import argparse
import csv
import win32com.client

client_id = 'xxxxx'
client_secret = 'xxxxxx'
tennant_id = 'xxxxx'
scope = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'

base_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/mailFolders/inbox'
  #  'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me'
#'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox'
end_point = base_url

AUTHORITY = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + tennant_id


SCOPES = [
    'Mail.Read',
    'Mail.ReadBasic',
    'Mail.ReadWrite'

]







cache = msal.SerializableTokenCache()

if os.path.exists('token_cache.bin'):
    cache.deserialize(open('token_cache.bin', 'r').read())

atexit.register(lambda: open('token_cache.bin', 'w').write(cache.serialize()) if cache.has_state_changed else None)

app = msal.PublicClientApplication(client_id, authority=AUTHORITY, token_cache=cache)

accounts = app.get_accounts()
result = None
if len(accounts) > 0:
    result = app.acquire_token_silent(SCOPES, account=accounts[0])

if result is None:
    flow = app.initiate_device_flow(scopes=SCOPES)
    if 'user_code' not in flow:
        raise Exception('Failed to create device flow')

    print(flow['message'])

    result = app.acquire_token_by_device_flow(flow)
print(result)

if 'access_token' in result:
    result = requests.get(end_point, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']})
    result.raise_for_status()
    print(result.json())

else:
    raise Exception('no access token in result')`
```

how to get total number of email count ?